# Difference between Text Embedding and Word Embedding

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, k-means, gensim, word2vec

I am working on a dataset of amazon alexa reviews and wish to cluster them in positive and negative clusters. I am using Word2Vec for vectorization so wanted to know the difference between **Text Embedding** and **Word Embedding**. Also, which one of them will be useful for my clustering of reviews (Please consider that I want to predict the cluster of any reviews that I enter.)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is better positioned on [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) forum or maybe [AI](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) one.

Comment: oh I didn't knew such a forum existed here, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text Embeddings are typically a way to aggregate a number of Word Embeddings for a sentence or a paragraph of text. There are various ways this can be done. The easiest way is to average word embeddings but not necessarily yielding best results.

Application-wise:

- [Doc2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) from `gensim`
- [par2vec vs. doc2vec](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17140/difference-between-paragraph2vec-and-doc2vec)